# raise_() function ignored

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qframe

I am new to python and I am trying to rewrite a GUI with PyQt5. The GUI I made was writen with Tkinter. I am using *frames* in order to bring up different pages. With Tkinter I succeeded to get pages to the front with tkraise() function. But with PyQt5 it seems as if the function gets ignored.

The file is a test file where I try different things befor adding it to my main file.
In the *Dothing* function I added a print("yes") function to see if it enters the function and it does, but it's not using the *raise_()* function somehow.

Could anybody explain me what I did wrong or maybe send me a link adress for more information so I search myself. I have already looked on the website of QT and other forums but I couldn't find a answer.

My file looks like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QApplication, QFrame, QLabel, QColorDialog)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QColor)

Lijst = ["Ferri", "Yvonne", "Ineke"] # , "Sidneger", "Deniel", "Tobie", "Nicol"

class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.List = [(255,0,0), (0,255,0), (0,0,255)]
        # self.List = Lijst
        # container = QFrame(self)
        self.setGeometry(300,300,300,300)

        self.Frames = {}
        for F in (self.List):
            selected_color = QColor(F[0],F[1],F[2])
            self.frame = QFrame(self)
            self.frame.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: %s}" % selected_color.name())
            self.frame.setGeometry(100, 0, 300, 300)
            Framas = Pages(self.frame, self, selected_color)
            self.Frames[F] = Framas

    def DoThing(self):
        self.Frames[(255, 0, 0)].raise_()
        print("yes")
        pass

    def DoThing2(self):
        self.Frames[(0, 255, 0)].raise_()
        pass

    def DoThing3(self):
        self.Frames[(0, 0, 255)].raise_()
        pass


class Pages(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, selected_color, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.controller = controller
        self.frame = parent

        self.button = QPushButton("Change", self.frame) # adding frame as parent
        self.button.move(10, 10)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.controller.DoThing)

        self.button2 = QPushButton("Change2", self.frame)
        self.button2.move(10, 50)
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.controller.DoThing2)

        self.button3 = QPushButton("Change3", self.frame)
        self.button3.move(10, 90)
        self.button3.clicked.connect(self.controller.DoThing3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Test_window = Test()
    Test_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having the source of the original code is difficult to know exactly what you require. So I'll try to help you with what I can.

First you must use only one `QFrame`, you for each iteration are creating 2: the `QFrame` that you set the color and the other the Page.

Secondly you are using `raise_()` on the Page since you add the page to the dictionary, but the Page does not have the color, but the other `QFrame`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication, QFrame)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QColor)

class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(300,300,300,300)

        colors = [(255,0,0), (0,255,0), (0,0,255)]
        self.Frames = {}
        for F in colors:
            selected_color = QColor(*F)
            frame = Pages(parent=self, controller=self)
            frame.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: %s}" % selected_color.name())
            frame.setGeometry(100, 0, 300, 300)
            self.Frames[F] = frame

    def DoThing(self):
        self.Frames[(255, 0, 0)].raise_()

    def DoThing2(self):
        self.Frames[(0, 255, 0)].raise_()

    def DoThing3(self):
        self.Frames[(0, 0, 255)].raise_()

class Pages(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.controller = controller

        self.button = QPushButton("Change", self) # adding frame as parent
        self.button.move(10, 10)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.controller.DoThing)

        self.button2 = QPushButton("Change2", self)
        self.button2.move(10, 50)
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.controller.DoThing2)

        self.button3 = QPushButton("Change3", self)
        self.button3.move(10, 90)
        self.button3.clicked.connect(self.controller.DoThing3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Test_window = Test()
    Test_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Ah now i understand what i did wrong. Because in the pages class i already make a Qframe because of inheritance and calling the super().
Thanks for the help!